# Magento 2, less debug by grunt exec, but images and fonts were ignored

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to debug less files, but after I try "grunt exec" with my new theme, it clears already created folder at `pub/static/frontend/My/design/en_US` and does not creates symlinks to fonts and images (or maybe should copy that?).
How to deploy links to styles with images and fonts by grunt or by other quick way for developers?

`dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js` configured with follow section:

```
mysample_design: {
    area: 'frontend',
    name: 'MySample/design',
    locale: 'en_US',
    files: [
        'css/styles-m',
        'css/styles-l'
    ],
    dsl: 'less'
},
```

At the Magento guide I can not find solution.

Comment: Old message but I'm facing the same issue. Any tips ? Thanks